# Вопрос по семантика HTML

Tags: html, теги, семантика

По семантике HTML можно в `main` вкладывать `section` или `article`?

Comment: [w3c, отличные примеры использования](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-main-element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Да, в `main` можно вложить всё что угодно, кроме `header` и `footer`.**

Тег `main` - для основного содержимого. В `main` нельзя (настоятельно не рекомендуется) вставлять теги `header` и `footer`.

Тег `section` - структурный тег - по типу `div`, если так понятней. Им отделяют "большие" блоки и секции.

Тег `article` - тег контейнера для контента. Предполагается, что внутрь будет помещен контент статьи - текст, картинки, видео\аудио, но никто не запрещает туда добавлять `div`.